# Postfix - Relay - authentificatin in Mysql

Tags: postfix, smtp, relay

I tryed to manage with a postfix server, my goal is that :

When 1 special user (test@example.com) try to send mail, it will use routing (using a relay server is OK) but I don't understand how to send authentification to the relay server to be authorized to send mail. I do that on my main.cf file :

```
relay_domains =
$mydestination
proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/relay_domains.cf

relay_recipient_maps =
    mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/relay_recipient_maps.cf
```

The first point is OK : I see that mail use relay specified into my mysql table to send mail
The second point has an issue : I think user/passsword are not send to relay so my mail is refused on it.
The file /etc/postfix/mysql/relay_recipient_maps.cf content is :

```
hosts       = 127.0.0.1:3306
user        = BDD_USER
password    = BDD_PASS
dbname      = BDD_DBNAME
query       = SELECT authentification FROM domain WHERE domain='%s' LIMIT 1
```

And in MySQL, "authentification" field contain user:password for relay authentification inplain text

Regards and have a good day !

Answer (score 0):

To authenticate with the relay server in Postfix, you need to configure the `smtp_sasl_auth_enable` parameter in your `main.cf` file.

1. Open your `main.cf` configuration file for Postfix.
2. Add or modify the following parameters:

```
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
```

3. Create a `sasl_passwd` file and specify the relay server's hostname or IP address, along with the authentication credentials:

```
relay.example.com    username:password
```

4. Generate the hash map file from the `sasl_passwd` file:

```
sudo postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```

5. Set the correct permissions for the `sasl_passwd.db` file:

```
sudo chown root:root /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.db
sudo chmod 0600 /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.db
```

6. Restart the postfix:

```
sudo service postfix restart
```

By configuring the `smtp_sasl_auth_enable` parameter and providing the authentication details in the `sasl_passwd` file, Postfix will use those credentials to authenticate with the relay server when sending emails.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I tryed to use Mysql for that so I need to use `smtp_sasl_password_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd` ? But when I do that, it seems that the auth data are not used anymore ?!

Comment: @PopFR1 
1. `sudo apt-get install postfix-mysql`

2. Create a file like /etc/postfix/mysql_relay_passwords.cf with MySQL connection and query details.

3. In `main.cf`, set `smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes` and `smtp_sasl_password_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_relay_passwords.cf`.

Comment: I already doing that but it seems that doesn't work - And if I trace Mysql traffic, idon't see the use of my query so probably mistake on my query - i will investigate